# javascript: Problema con Array Dinámico

Tags: javascript, array, recursión, programación-funcional

Necesito saber cómo puedo hacer lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo un `input` y un botón, la idea es llenar este `input` con un nombre, en este caso el sistema que estoy haciendo trata de categorías, así que seria el nombre de una categoría, como por ejemplo *Zapatos*. Una vez lleno el `input` le daría click al botón que tiene a su lado `[+]`, al darle se vacía el `input` y su contenido se guarda dentro de un array de la siguiente forma:

```
categorias = [
 {
  name: "Zapatos"
  sub: []
 }
]
```

Y la interfaz ahora luciría así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es decir, debajo de aquellos `input` y botón, tendría que aparecer un `input` y un botón idénticos a los anteriores pero con la única diferencia de que encima tiene el nombre de la categoría anterior. El nuevo sería para agregar una subcategoría, un hijo de la categoría *Zapatos*. Es decir que, podría escribir: *Nike* y darle al botón y el resultado en el array sería el siguiente:

```
categorias = [
  {
    name: "Zapatos"
    sub: [
      {
        name: "Nike"
        sub: []
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

A partir de aquí podría elegir agregar más categorías o agregarle más subcategorías a *Zapatos*, o agregarle una categoría a *Nike*, por ejemplo, una talla, *23*.

El problema yace en esta parte:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No sé cómo decirle que *Nike* tiene que estar dentro del array `sub[]` de *Zapatos*.

La idea es poder hacer esta adición de manera infinita, ponerle a una categoría las subcategorías que quiera y a una subcategoría otra subcategoría y así cuantas veces sea necesario.

Aquí les dejo una pequeña imagen de la idea:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y a continuación les dejo el código de uno de mis miserables intentos por hacer esto:

```js
let mainDiv = document.querySelector('#mainDiv');
   let mainButton = document.querySelector('#mainButton');
   let mainInput = document.querySelector('#mainInput');

   let categories = [];
   let elements = [];

   const tmp =(name)=>{
    return `
    <b>${name}</b>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Category" name="name" id="mainInput">
    <button id="mainButton">+</button>
     `;
    }

    mainButton.addEventListener('click', ()=>createNewCategory(mainInput.value, 'category'));

    function createNewCategory(name, type) {
      let id = categories.length;
      let elementID = elements.length;
      elements[elementID] = document.createElement('div');
      elements[elementID].innerHTML = tmp(name);
      elements[elementID].classList.add('container');
      if (type === 'category'){
        categories[id] = {
          name: name,
          sub: []
        }

        mainDiv.appendChild(elements[elementID]);
        newBtn = elements[elementID].querySelector('button');
        newInput = elements[elementID].querySelector('input');
        newBtn.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
          createNewCategory(newInput.value, 'subcategory');
          dc(newInput);
        });
        dc(mainInput);
    }
    else
    {
        ///??????
    }
}
// Debug and clean
const dc =(input)=>{
  console.log(categories);
  input.value = '';
}
```

```css
.container{
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 4px;
  margin: 4px;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" id="mainDiv">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Category" name="name" id="mainInput">
  <button id="mainButton">+</button>
</div>
```

He tratado con *POO* y recursividad pero no consigo la manera de hacerlo.

PD: La parte con signos de interrogación es donde usualmente no sé como proseguir y termino haciendo todo mal.

Comment: Y cuál es tu objetivo final? No está claro lo que preguntas

Comment: El objetivo final es usar ese array para subirlo luego a una base de datos. El chiste es tener un sistema para agregar categorias y subcategorias de manera dinámica y sin tocar código, para que luego estas se muestren en una página principal. Si necesitas más detalles hazme saber.

Comment: Saludos. Te puedo dar sugerencias haber cual te parece realizable. Por cada nivel generar su `agregar` y demás operaciones, otra es que la función con cada operación le pases el objeto (digamos) contenedor de las subcategorias y realizar así las operaciones. Son las 2 opciones que se me ocurre para que las realices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const mainDiv = document.querySelector('.container');
const mainButton = document.querySelector('.container > button');
const mainInput = document.querySelector('.container > input');

const categories = [];

const tmp = (name, index) => {
    return `
        <b>${name}</b>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Category" data-index="${index}">
        <button data-index="${index}">+</button>
    `;
}

mainButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    createNewCategory(mainDiv, mainInput);
});

function createNewCategory(container, input) {
    const name = input.value;
    const dataIndex = input.getAttribute('data-index');
    const indexes = dataIndex
        .split('.')
        .filter(Boolean);
    const parentCategory = indexes
        .reduce((result, category) => {
            result = result[category].sub;
            return result;
        }, categories);
    const elementID = parentCategory.length;

    parentCategory[elementID] = {
        name,
        sub: []
    };

    const element = document.createElement('div');
    element.innerHTML = tmp(name, `${dataIndex ? `${dataIndex}.` : ''}${elementID}`);
    element.classList.add('container');

    container.appendChild(element);
    const newBtn = element.querySelector('button');
    const newInput = element.querySelector('input');
    newBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
        createNewCategory(element, newInput);
    });

    console.log(categories);
}
```

```css
.container {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 4px;
    margin: 4px;
    width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Category" data-index="">
    <button data-index="">+</button>
  </div>

  <script src="js.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```